# Cannot search a single letter

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, search

It does not seem that we can search a one-letter word.  When we type a single letter in the search box, it takes us to an explanation of how to search instead of the search result.  Example: [Search 僕](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%83%95).

Many words in Japanese consists of a single letter, and this restriction is pretty inconvenient.

Comment: We seem to be breaking a lot of the SE systems.  Guess that's what we get for being the first site revolving around a language totally different from English.

Answer (score 8):

A workaround or kind of this is

- to put it in the double quotes ["僕"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%E5%83%95%22),
- or (a hack?) by putting dummy stars [僕**](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%83%95**)
- or old but still usable wildcard expressions [僕~~](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%83%95~~)

Comment: I have never thought of adding double quotes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since a search change a few weeks ago, this now works.  It was important for our sites with heavy use of unicode characters that this be supported...so now it is.